# Request and Cheerio scraping sometimes wont show html

Tags: javascript, request, cheerio

I'm trying to make a program that scrapes each Trading Card price for every game given a url.

The issue that I'm having is that it returns some Trading Card prices but not all of them. It should return arround 40-50 and only returns about 10 results and the rest are returned as "undefined" values.

I'm also doing it by passing my personal Steam profile cookies so it won't block my requests and also show items in my local currency.

```js
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

// here I replace my own cookies
const webTradeEligibility = '';
const browserid = '';
const steamLoginSecure = '';
const sessionid = '';

function filterTradingCard(gameId){

    var options = {
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=&category_753_Game%5B%5D=tag_app_' + gameId + '&category_753_cardborder%5B%5D=tag_cardborder_0&category_753_item_class%5B%5D=tag_item_class_2&appid=753#p1_price_asc',
        'headers': {
            'Cookie': 'webTradeEligibility='+ webTradeEligibility +' ; browserid='+ browserid +' ; steamLoginSecure= ' + steamLoginSecure +' ; sessionid=' + sessionid
        }
    };

    request(options, (error, response, html)=> {
        
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            let tradingCardPrice = $('.normal_price').text().trim();
            let tradingCardPriceTrimmed = tradingCardPrice.trim().split(' ')[3];

            // this line sometimes prints 'undefined' and others returns the string that I want
            console.log(tradingCardPriceTrimmed);
        }
    })
}



function getInfo(){
    request('https://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=Price_ASC&maxprice=840&category1=998&category2=29', (error, response, html)=> { // gets price and game name
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);

            // gets game titles
            $('.col.search_capsule').each(function(i,element) { 
                let gameId = $(this).find('img').attr('src').split("/")[5].trim(); // grabs game ID from img src and then trims the ID

                let price = $(this).nextUntil('.col.search_price.discounted.responsive_secondrow').text().trim(); // gets game price
                price = price.split('$')[2];
                price = parseFloat(price.replace(',','.'));

                // filters if games has trading cards
                filterTradingCard(gameId);
            });

        } else {
            console.log("Wrong response code: " + response.statusCode);
        }
    });
}

async function getList(){
  getInfo();
}

getList();
```

Here is an example of what it returns (I simplified it but the list is longer).

Numeric values like "1,92ARS$" are the ones that I want. Also would like to know why I'm getting undefined and try to turn them into numeric values too.

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
1,92ARS$
2,68ARS$
2,91ARS$
1,77ARS$
undefined
undefined
3,67ARS$
4,40ARS$
3,79ARS$
4,54ARS$
undefined
undefined
undefined
3,96ARS$
```

Comment: When there are 10 "undefined" result returned, have you checked what's actually in the "html" ?

Comment: Can you give an example of the correct return values and the incorrect return values for us?

Comment: @Neverever The class where is grabs the price from is correct. The problem is that sometimes it returns "undefined" and others it returns the price.

Comment: @AaronMeese, the correct values should be something like "ARS$ 4,54" but it also prints "undefined" values

Comment: I would recommend print both tradingCardPrice & tradingCardPriceTrimmed together. So that you can see what was the price before trimmed. It might be the .split(' ')[3] is causing the problem

Comment: @Neverever It does the same but instead of printing "undefined" it prints out blank spaces